# IntelliJ classpath issue after moving source from test to src

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I developed some classes inside my `src/test` folder. Once I was happy with their behaviour, I moved just the actual classes into my `src/java` folder, leaving the actual test cases inside the `src/test` folder.

IntelliJ happily did the refactoring for me, and reports no compiler errors when viewing the project. However, when I attempt to run a test case, the compile step complains that the newly moved package does not exist. IntelliJ navigates to the references classes happily though, so it doesn't look like a setup issue.

I've discovered that if I move the source files from the package they're in the `src/java` folder to a different `src/java` folder then the test cases begin working, but I'd still like to know what happened.

I've attempted the obvious restarting IntelliJ / the computer and invalidating caches. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is it a maven project?

Comment: No, it's a fairly custom structure Ant project. I've discovered that if I move the source files from the package they're in the `src/java` folder to a different `src/java` folder then the test cases begin working, but I'd still like to know what happened.